# Trigger NgChecked in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to work out a way of triggering NgChecked to re-evaluate it's expression after a user submits a form (which reloads the data). Ideally the trigged would be after the data has been reloaded, so the checkbox state is in line with that of the data and the amendments that have been made.

I've tried calling the expression directly after loadData() is called, however to no avail.

Do I instead need to use something like NgUpdate?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Please see my code below:

view.html

```
<form ng-submit="updateinfo(item.downloadID); showDetails = ! showDetails;">

                        <input class="form-control" style="margin:5px 3px;" type="text"
                               ng-model="item.title" value="{{item.title}}"
                               placeholder="{{item.title}}"/>

                        <div class="checkbox" style="margin:5px 3px;">
                            <label for="downloadLive">
                                <input name="downloadLive" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.dlLive" ng-checked="liveCheckBoxState(item.dlLive);" ngTrueValue="1" ngFalseValue ="0"> Download live
                            </label>
                        </div>


                        <input class="btn btn-default form-control" style="margin:5px 3px;" type="submit"/>
                    </form>
```

controllers.js

```
// a scope function to edit a record
    $scope.updateinfo = function(downloadID) {
        id = downloadID
        var result = $scope.items.filter(function( items ) {
            return items.downloadID == id;
        });
        updatedata = $scope.items
        $http({
            method : 'PUT',
            url :  '/view1/downloadedit/'+id,
            data : result
        });
        $scope.loadData();
    };
//return correct state checkbox for downloadlive
    $scope.liveCheckBoxState = function(dlLive) {
        console.log(dlLive);
        if (dlLive == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    };
// a scope function to load the data
    $scope.loadData = function () {
        $http.get('/view1/downloadData').success(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    };
    $scope.loadData();
```

Comment: All angular directives are reevaluated in each digest cycle. Can you make a fiddle which reproduces the problem?

Comment: not really clear what issue is. Appears that form is part of `ng-repeat`? You already have `ng-model` bound to data  , the `liveCheckBoxState` should run automatically when data changes...so hard to tell what your problem is. A demo in plunker or jsfiddle would help

Comment: Cheers I will put it up now. Basically liveCheckBoxState isn't reevaluating

Comment: just updating it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6khqh/

Comment: demo is worthless without sample data and being error free on page load. Much easier to load sample data using plunker as demo platform. Just create sample json file and point url at it

Comment: Here's what I've got so far, which is still not working properly :S http://plnkr.co/edit/EfdWon42VVoZ84gDYt2n?p=preview I'm pretty new to this, and the app is mostly built with Ruby/Sinatra so I'm struggling to get it working in this context.